# Is there a way to fullscreen python cmd window without using os lines and columns

Tags: python

I would like to make an application where if you run it, the cmd goes fullscreen is there a way to do that without using columns and rows with `import os`. Or will that be my only bet? I would like to have it setup like this

```py
import example

full.screen()

application here <- can be whatever.
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Other solution are accepted as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import time
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)
time.sleep(20)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Function will do what you want :

```
import os
import ctypes
import msvcrt
import subprocess

from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = wintypes.HWND
kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize.restype = wintypes._COORD
kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)
user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = (wintypes.HWND, ctypes.c_int)

def maximize_console(lines=None):
    fd = os.open('CONOUT$', os.O_RDWR)
    try:
        hCon = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd)
        max_size = kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hCon)
        if max_size.X == 0 and max_size.Y == 0:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
    cols = max_size.X
    hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
    if cols and hWnd:
        if lines is None:
            lines = max_size.Y
        else:
            lines = max(min(lines, 9999), max_size.Y)
        subprocess.check_call('mode.com con cols={} lines={}'.format(
                                cols, lines))
        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Explanation:

1. It calls `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize` in order to figure how big it can make the window, with the option to specify a number of `lines` that exceeds this in order to get a scrollback buffer
2. To do the work of resizing the screen buffer it simply calls mode.com via `subprocess.check_call`
3. Finally, it gets the console window handle via `GetConsoleWindow` and calls `ShowWindow` to maximize it.

Comment: This gves an error:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\Nieuwe map\cmd.py", line 39, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 185, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Looks like you’re using Python 2.7?

Comment: @MdeGraaff , I edited the answer you can check it out now